# How to use anonymous struct or class?

Tags: c++, class, struct, anonymous

So, it's possible to declalre anonymous class or struct but how to I make it useful?

```
int main() {
    class{
        int ClassVal;
    };
    struct{
        short StructVal;
    };
    StructVal = 5;   //StructVal is undefined
    ClassVal = 5;    //ClassVal is undefined too?
    return 0;
}
```

if you put both of them outside of main function they will be inaccessible as well.
I'm asking this only because it's somehow intersting :)

EDIT:
Why union outside of main function (at global scope) must be static declared
for example:

```
static struct {
    int x;
};
int main() {
   //...
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could say what language you're using.

Comment: @skaffman, I'm using C++, i've put a C++ tag bellow my post. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous classes and structures may be used to directly define a variable:

```
int main()
{
    class
    {
        int ClassVal;
    } classVar;

    struct
    {
        short StructVal;
    } structVar;

    structVar.StructVal = 5;
    classVar.ClassVal = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

The above is not very common like that, but very common when used in unions as described by Simon Richter in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

These are most useful in the form of nested `struct` and `union`:

```
struct typed_data {
    enum type t;
    union {
        int i;                       // simple value
        struct {
            union {                  // any of these need a length as well
                char *cp;
                unsigned char *ucp;
                wchar_t *wcp;
            };
            unsigned int len;
        };
    };
 };
```

Now `typed_data` is declared as a type with the members `t`, `i`, `cp`, `ucp`, `wcp` and `len`, with minimal storage requirements for its intended use.

Comment: that means they can be used only within another class/struct/union but not inside a function or at global scope? if so why we can declare an anonimous class at global scope then? and why union in that case must be static and class/struct doesn't? and why such classes/structs can't be used theh, thanks alot.

Comment: Just because you can does not mean it makes sense -- a lot of constructs in C/C++ exist mainly because it would have made the grammar rules more complicated to forbid them.

Comment: C++ is an diplomatic language then, means: some part is always incomprehensible :D